# rerender component when tab is choosed react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm using TabNavigator from react-navigation to navigate through 3 component. My TabNavigator component look like this:

```
import routeOnMap from '../screens/routsOnMap.js';
import meditatinWalk from '../screens/meditationWalk.js';
import newWordToWalkOn from '../screens/newWordToWalkOn.js';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

import {
  StackNavigator,
  NavigationActions,
  TabNavigator,
  TabBarBottom,
} from 'react-navigation';

import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default TabNavigator(
{
  MeditatinWalk: { screen: meditatinWalk },
  NewWordToWalkOn: { screen: newWordToWalkOn },
  RouteOnMap: { screen: routeOnMap },

},
{
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      let iconName;
      if (routeName === 'MeditatinWalk') {
        iconName = `ios-walk${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
      } else if (routeName === 'NewWordToWalkOn') {
        iconName = `ios-add-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
      } else if (routeName === 'RouteOnMap') {
        iconName = `ios-map${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
      }

      // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
      // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
      return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
    },
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#626A41',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  },
  tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false,
}
);
```

I want to rerender whats inside my NewWordToWalkOn component when it's when it is pressed/tabbed. The code I would like to rerender is whats inside the componentDidMount() methode in the NewWordToWalkOn component.

```
//imports

export default class NewWordToWalkOn extends Component {
constructor() {
 super()
   this.state = {
   words: [],
 };
}

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
 title:
  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#626A41'}}> Vælg nye ord at vandre på </Text>,
headerLeft: null,
headerRight:
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginRight: 10 }}
    onPress={ () => MeditatinWalk._logout() }>
      <Text
        style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#626A41'}}>
        Log ud
      </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
});

 componentDidMount() {
  //code that needs rerendered
 }


render() {

)

return (
  <ScrollView style={styles.wrapper}>
    //all the elements
  </ScrollView>
);
}
}
```

Any suggestions how to rerender?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to update your view when the tab is pressed, try subscribe navigation lifecycle event with [this.props.navigation.addListener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle).

Example:

```
class NewWordToWalkOn extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.navigationWillFocusListener = props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
      // do something like this.setState() to update your view
    })
  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.navigationWillFocusListener.remove()
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay that help and now it's working. I had to make a new methode for the code inside the componentDidMount() methode and call it in your code in the addListener and now it's working. Thanks for your help :-)